# mixing c++ class inheritance and initializer lists. An unsolved puzzle in my mind

Tags: c++, derived-class, initializer-list

I have 4 classes

```
class A { //a base class
    public:
    A(ostringstream* os){ oss2=os; }
    ostringstream* oss2;
};

class B : public A{ // a derived class 
    public:
    B(ostringstream* os):A(os){};
};

class C { //class where oss is actually declared
    public:
    C(){};
    ostringstream oss;
};
```

and finally (the kicker): a derived class from "C" , that needs to pass a reference to `oss` around.

```
class D : public C{
    public:
    B b(&oss);
};
```

in line `B b(&oss);` I get the error

> error: expected identifier before ‘&’ token

I honestly don't know if I am playing with fire here. The basic idea is that I want some functions of A to write to a common output stream.

This is not a logging class but I see that some loggers declare a static oss variable and allow everyone to write there. I would prefer to avoid that and instantiate my oss in the (logically) correct location. In my case, that is in class C.

I think (but I could be wrong) that the error here is that I am trying to provide a reference to a variable (oss) through the declaration of `B b`. Is that right? Instead an initializer list should be used to provide the value to the constructor. But I am not sure how to implement this (and test if it compiles).

Comment: You're a real `b(&oss)`!

Comment: In `B b(&oss);`, is `b` supposed to be a member variable? Because to the compiler it looks like it's a function declaration, and it complains because there seems to be a parameter type missing in `&oss`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a field of type `B` in `D`, you should just declare it there and initialize it in the constructor, as you already hinted at:

```
class D : public C{
  public:
    D() : 
      C(),    // You can leave this out, the compiler will do it for you
      b(&oss) // Once the C part is constructed you can pass in its field.
    {}

  private: // ?
    B b;
};
```

But depending on your situation, there may be a better solution in terms of design. For example, if `C` is a base class for output, and `A` is a class that needs to do some logging, you could go with a solution like this:

```
class A { // worker base class
    public:
        A(C* logger) : logger(logger) {}
    private:
        C* logger;
};

class B : public A{ // a derived class 
    public:
        B(C* logger) : A(logger) {};
};

class C { // logging class
    public:
        C(){};  
        virtual ~C() {};
        virtual void Log(const std::string& message) = 0;
};

class D : public C { // a derived class
  public:
      D() {} 
      virtual void Log(const std::string& message) 
      {
        this->oss << message;
      }
  private:
      ostringstream oss;
}

// In main:
D streamLogger;
A worker(&streamLogger);
```

Now `A` doesn't care what it outputs to, just pass it a class which supports `Log`ging a message and let polymorphism handle the rest. In fact, if you want to have a logging method that sends emails, just create a new derivative of `C` and pass it into the same `A` instance.

Comment: I think you forgot to derive `D` from `C`.

Comment: I think so too. Thanks @JamesAdkison! I also forgot to pass in the logger as pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to properly declare a `B` data member and then construct is properly.

```
class D : public C
{
public:
    B b; // Declare a 'B' type

    // 'B' must be instantiated with a single argument therefore it must be
    // constructed in the initializer list
    D() : b(&oss) {}
};
```